# JS- onClick on multiple things

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a simple table where is a checkbox at each line. If user click on this checkbox it use onClick function and send a information via JS to another PHP file to delete ROW with `id = $id`, it works correctly. Problem start when I click multiple checkboxes without refreshing a site.

This is how HTML looks like:

```
echo '<td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="check" value="'.$row["id"].'" onClick="aa()"></label></td>';
```

This is how JQuery looks like:

```
function aa()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?id=" + document.getElementById("check").value, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;;
}
```

And finaly my .php file:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id=$id";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I am still just amater so maybe I'm thinking wrong but in my eyes this JS scould always send .php info when user clck ChekBox, so why it's not sending it like that?

Thank you all for your advise.

Comment: For multiple deletes you have to change your sql query a bit. `DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN (val, val, val);` Something like that.

Comment: Your function uses `getElmementById` each time it is called and looks for `check`. This is problematic as each ID must be unique.

Comment: I think you're doing it wrong, what is your goal?
Why don't you add a Delete button which deletes all selected data in the table, you could also add a Select All button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be for you to send the row's ID value into the onClick method.  That way you're only having to make the service call in the method, not also look up the value (and you know the value you're getting will be correct.)

```html
echo '<td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="check" value="'.$row["id"].'" onClick="aa('.$row["id"].')"></label></td>';
```

Also, make sure your input ID attribute value is unique for every row, as that'll cause problems with doing ID lookups.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
input type="checkbox" id="check" ...
```

You are giving the id "check" to every checkbox. That will break things anyway because in HTML there should not be more than on element on a page with the same ID. But it also means that when you do this

```
document.getElementById("check")
```

It doesn't know which row you are talking about.

You don't need to get the element by id; an event object is automatically passed to the click function, and the target of the event will be the checkbox

```
function deleteItem(e) {
    var box = e.target;
    var value = box.value;
    // delete the value ...
}
```

For info on the event parameter (e) see http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Jquery at all. You should define the function you want to execute when a click is performed in every checkbox.

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').click(function()
{
  var sId = $(this).attr('id');
  // call you ajax with this sId as the ID
});
```

But remember that you have to insert the jquery library with a script tag in your head. And also that this code must be called when the dom is loaded.

Comment: I am starting to be a bit lost, sorry. Is there a chance you can edit my code to give me better example?

Comment: Frist you need to include the jquery library with the <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> in your <head></head>

Comment: Then, you need to initialize your event handlers for the checkbox, and you have to do it when all the page has been loaded, that is $(function() {
    call_init_function();
});

Comment: call_init_function is the function that has the code I have put and listens to the click event of every element of the page that has the atribute TYPE = 'checkbox'. For every item, sId has the Id of that element. Maybe you should read more about css selectors ans jquery to fully understand how juqery works.

Comment: Given that the OP is successfully using ajax to delete one item (while having trouble deleting more than one), it is clear that they are loading the jQuery script and that they understand the basics.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't recognize JQuery in his code..only regular javascript.

Comment: Yes you are right, s/he is not using jQuery. I see that now. But nonetheless that isn't the problem with the code. The problem is that the id is the same for each checkbox, so the code you supplied would also fail

Comment: I was trying to explain my solution that uses selectors so every checkbox will have its click event, instead of just one of the checkboxes, that is his current problem. But to explain tht code I needed to explain everything....lol

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is with

```
document.getElementById("checkbox")
```

which will always refer to the same element and might be causing your problem. maybe passing in an argument to aa() with the row id instead of using the value of the element such as

```
echo (' ... onClick="aa('. $row["id"] .') ... ')
```